# method that adds values together if ID is the same

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model

Hello I am currently trying to figure out how to add values together if their item id's are the same in my SQL database. Here is a view of my database

[image: Database]

As you can see two of the values have the same "ItemID" with a value of 117. I want my method to return the combined quantities of the two values so in this case I would want it to return the value "14"

Here is my method inside my model that pulls the item quantity

```
  public int Available(Item i)
        {

            OffSiteItemDetails d = ItemDetails.Where(x => x.itemID == i.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (d == null)
                return 0;
            return d.qty;
        }
```

but just not sure how to combine the values when there is more than one value with the same ID

Comment: You have no examples in your sample data where the `id`s are the same.  But the answer to your question is `GROUP BY`.

Comment: itemID @GordonLinoff and I need to pull the value through my MVC web application as I need to display the value. So not sure how to use group by in that context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int Available(Item i)
{

    List<OffSiteItemDetails> d = ItemDetails.Where(x => x.itemID == i.ID).ToList();
    if (d == null || d.Count < 1)
        return 0;

    return d.Sum(x => x.qty);
}
```

Comment: do I need to create the Count and Sum methods? Or  should they be automatic? I get errors currently with the method like that

Comment: Sum is a part of the LINQ package, but if the "Where" method works, "Sum" should be working as well. Sum only works with IEnumerable<> in this context. I've edited the answer

Comment: Awesome, I have no errors now but unfortunately it still isn't correctly working right now. I tested it on my homepage by checking the value it was returning and it isn't adding all of them.  It's just returning the quantity of a single one. (Returning 7 instead of 14)